# Which EC2 types don't require a VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I need to add some capacity to a Spark cluster and seem to have run into the upper limit w/re which instance types I can use without starting a VPC.

The code I've inherited to start said cluster is a bit of Groovy spaghetti and doesn't seem to be lending itself to incorporating a VPC too readily. Hence the need to work w/out.

Comment: Well heck - I would delete this but it seems there are stern warnings once an answer exists / is accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's not just the instance limit on the account that you can easily request Amazon to raise?

According to [the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-vpc.html#vpc-only-instance-types), these are the only instance types restricted to a VPC at this time:

- C4
- M4
- T2
- X1

All other instance types should still be available in EC2 Classic.

Comment: Hmm.. I guess I must have hit all the ones that require a VPC. Looks like it's a go with c3.

Comment: It sounds like you are just running up against your service limits. Instead of switching to different instance types you should just submit a ticket with AWS to have the limit increased on the account.

Comment: It's a question of available RAM on the boxes.